# Ubuntu git pull merge options

Tags: git, ubuntu

On Ubuntu terminal, I pulled from master and after I chose option
^X (Exit) it asked if I want to save. I chose Yes and now I have these options.

What do I choose to just do a normal git pull and merge. Im guessing ^T (to files) final answer

M-D DOS format

M-M Mac format

M-A append

M-P prepend

M-B backup file

T to files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the default editor `nano`. `git pull` results in a non-fast-forward merge and a merge commit is created. The editor pops up so that the user can edit the default commit message. After the editing is done, you can just press `Ctrl-X`, `Y`, and then `Enter` to save and close the editor.

`Ctrl-X` instructs to exit. `Y` for yes to save the changes if any. `Enter` to confirm the file path you want to save.